# Red textbox border color

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form with one textbox. I want to check when the textbox value is empty and make some sort of red border surrounding the textbox itself when it's empty.

```
if (document.getElementById('pageh').value == "") {
    alert("One of the fields is empty.");
    return false;
}
```

That's my validation, but how do I add the red border?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var field = document.getElementById('pageh');

if (field.value == "") {
    document.getElementById('pageh').style.border = "solid 1px red";
    alert("One of the fields is empty.");
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like that?

```
var textbox = document.getElementById("pageh");
if (textbox.value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "") === "") {
    textbox.style.border = "1px solid #ff0000";
}
```

Note, don't be afraid of `replace` part: this is just [cross-browser text trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim).